# Vector motion blur and Reelsmart Motion Blur

Tags: compositing-nodes, motion-blur

Is it possible to add vector motion blur to a rendered image sequence without using third party software like Reelsmart Motion Blur (RSMB) in After Effects? If not, is there a way to render a motion vector pass in Blender that's compatible with Reelsmart Motion Blur?

What's the advantage of RSMB?

Thanks!